# How to show Out of stock Items in android application

Tags: java, android

I want to display FIRST in stock items THEN out of stock items. Within those two groups, the products should be alphabetized.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please post any code you have attempted.

Comment: We don't know your data structure nor where it is stored. If it is in an SQLite DB, then you should write the SQL query that sorts it that way.

Answer (score 0):

KOTLIN:

```
val sortedList = list.sortedWith(compareBy({ it.isInStock }))
```

JAVA:

```
list.sort(comparing(Type::isInStock))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Comparator` to sort.

You can refer below method. It sorts on multiple fields. Change the method as per your need.

```
private static void sort(List<Item> items) {

    Collections.sort(items, new Comparator() {

        public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {

            String x1 = ((Item) o1).getName();
            String x2 = ((Item) o2).getName();
            int sComp = x1.compareTo(x2);

            if (sComp != 0) {
               return sComp;
            } 

            Integer x1 = ((Item) o1).getInventoryCount();
            Integer x2 = ((Item) o2).getInventoryCount();
            return x1.compareTo(x2);
    }});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just sort your list with the number of stock available:

```
Collections.sort(items, (a, b) -> a.getStockInt().compareTo(b.getStockInt()));
```